# find the brightest pixel in the camera preview

Tags: android, colors, camera, tracker

need a help to fix these line of code to find brightest pixel and its coordinates (x,y) and draw a bitmap over it. 
i have android preview live camera and want to scan the screen my process code is within onPreviewFframe by doing for loop and comparing preset float brightestValue to every value of pixels[]. my canvas staticaly draw circle in top left of the screen.
i expect dinamic change of circle position on the camera surfaceview while change the direction of the camera. sorry if my english is bad grammatically
thank you

```
public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
Preview preview;
int brightestX = 0; // X-coordinate of the brightest video pixel
int brightestY = 0; // Y-coordinate of the brightest video pixel

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Paint p = new Paint ();
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
    canvas.drawCircle(brightestX,brightestY,20,p);
    preview = new Preview(this);
    preview.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);
    }

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Parameters parameters;
    private Camera.Size previewSize;
    private int[] pixels;
    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        try {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
            parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            previewSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        //set the camera's settings
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //transforms NV21 pixel data into RGB pixels
        decodeYUV420SP(pixels, data, previewSize.width,  previewSize.height);
        float brightestValue = 0; // Brightness of the brightest video pixel
        for (int y = 0; y < previewSize.height ; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < previewSize.width; x++) {
                // Get the color stored in the pixel
                float pixelBrightness = pixels[previewSize.width*previewSize.height];
                // If that value is brighter than any previous, then store the
                // brightness of that pixel, as well as its (x,y) location
                if (pixelBrightness > brightestValue) {
                    brightestValue = pixelBrightness;
                    brightestY = y;
                    brightestX = x;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    //Method from Ketai project! Not mine! See below...
    void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {

        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {       int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }
                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0)                  r = 0;               else if (r > 262143)
                    r = 262143;
                if (g < 0)                  g = 0;               else if (g > 262143)
                    g = 262143;
                if (b < 0)                  b = 0;               else if (b > 262143)
                    b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `canvas.drawCircle(brightestX,brightestY,20,p);` after updating the position in the `onPreviewFrame` method, so the code looks like this:

```
 if (pixelBrightness > brightestValue) {
                    brightestValue = pixelBrightness;
                    brightestY = y;
                    brightestX = x;
                    drawCircleOnNewPosition() // method that calls canvas.drawCircle
                }
```

Comment: hi @FruitAddict. i also doubt if my for loop is works correctly.